# How can I implement a pluginable class and register in different file

Tags: python

I have two files , `judger.py` and `judgemethods.py` .

When `Judger` class in `judger.py` is doing his job , it will go through the judge methods it has (A list maybe) to check if something fit some rules.

For Example :

In `judgemethods.py` , I write a simple judge method and use a magic method to register it to `Judger`

```
@some_magic_method
def better_than_ten(num):
    return num > 10
```

In `Judger.py`

```
class Judger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = []

    def judge(self, thing):
        for method in self.methods :
            if method(thing):
                return True
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    judger = Judger()
    # Judge a integer for example
    number = 11
    judger.judge(number)
```

I will get `True` .

I wonder how can i elegantly implement a decorator or something that will automatically register function to `Judger` object in different file .

Comment: Does `Judger.py` `import` `judgemethods.py`?

Comment: @Tichodroma  ```import``` is fine , and not ```import``` is better .

Comment: You execute `Judger.py`. How is it supposed to magically discover `judgemethods.py` if you don't import it?

Comment: @Tichodroma Sorry  , I am not quite sure whether I can implement it with or without ```import``` . It's mush better If the solution without using ```import``` exists .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to register the methods defined `judgemethods.py` in the `judge.py`.
There also in fact seems there is no sane way for `Judge` to know what the methods are without at least importing `judgemethods.py`.

If you're okay with importing things, here's what you could:

```
# In judgemethods.py

# A global list of judge_methods
JUDGE_METHOD_LIST = []

# Your decorator to add stuff to this list
def register_judge_method(f):
    JUDGE_METHOD_LIST.append(f)
    return f

@ register_judge_method
def some_judging_method():
    print 'Judging you'
```

---

```
# In judge.py
import judgemethods as jmYou can always import judgemethods.py 


# To access it from within the Judge class
# Add it in your __init__
class Judge(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = jm.JUDGE_METHOD_LIST
    # ...

    def call(self):
        for f in jm.JUDGE_METHOD_LIST:
            print f
            # <function some_judging_method at 0x7f9bacdb46e0>
            f()
            # 'Judging You'
```

---

Edit: OP wants to know if he'll have to import `judgemethods.py` again in every file where he wants to use the `Judge` class

No, that's not required.

```
# main.py

from judge import Judge

j = Judge()
j.call()
```

Comment: He want's to 'register' in `judge.methods`.

Comment: @Tichodroma `self.methods = jm.JUDGE_METHOD_LIST` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But what if I am trying to initialize the ```Judge``` object at another file like ```main.py``` , Must I import ```judgemethods.py``` and ```Judger.py``` and initialize ```Judger``` with ```jm.JUDGE_METHOD_LIST``` ?

Comment: Yes, it will work, python's scoping is such that it will, you will not have to import `judgemethods.py` in `main.py`.

Comment: @ffledgling Thanks for the help . I am going to refactor it .